Next.js + Vercel - "gamestate" of my Game switches between two states when it is LIVE on Vercel, load balancer?
In my game, you have to click a button to increase the users counter by +1.
Client

The vue.js Client App just provides the button.

Clicking the button makes API requests to the backend

Display the API response "counterValue"


Server

The backend , increases and returns the users "counterValue"

The "users" and their increasing "counterValue" are persistend over different API calls.


No serverside statemanagement is used. Code:

import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
let cachedUsers: User[] = []
...

-----------------------------------------
When testing the game locally, everything works fine!
The Problem:
(origState --> newState):
When the Game is deployed to Vercel! then it can happen, after clicking the button verry fast (counter = 100) (origState), you get another gamestate, with counter = 0. (newState)
(newState --> origState):
When I increase the counter in newState quickly to 20, it can happen that is **jumps back to origState! **with counter = 100).
(origState --> newState):
I click button many times from (100 to 170), switches back to newState! with counter = 20.
(newState --> origState):
When I increase quickly the counter from 20 to 230 in newState, **jumps back to origState! **with counter = 170).
...
----------------
My Thoughts

Locally this never happens.

I think, there might be a load balancer or something. A "second server" for handling the requests :D Because it only switches between origState and newState... not more.


I did some internet research for this but it's hard to search for this problem.

You are expecting the server to "hold state". Locally it does not happen because of the local vs. deployed differences. If you need to "hold state" in your backend, you must do that with a Database. Check out "Vercel KV", for example.
Even if you use another service, like Heroku, you are at risk of losing information if the server "restarts".
Please check https://vercel.com/docs/functions/concepts#functions-lifecycle
